# Span of Density operators (Positive Semi-definite matrices of Trace one)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, operator-theory, positive-semidefinite

While reading basic-mathematics of quantum mechanics I came across a statement -

> "For every complex euclidean space $\cal X$ there exists spanning sets
>   of the space $L({\cal X})$ consisting of only density operators".

Here,

1. $\cal X$ is euclidean space, say ${\mathbb C}^n$;
2. $L({\cal X})$ correspond to linear operators over ${\cal X}$ which is just complex matrices of $n\times n$ size; and
3. Density operators are just positive semi-definite matrices of trace one.

Now, I do not quite understand this that linear combination of positive semi-definite matrices should be at least a symmetric matrix, then how can span cover all the elements in $L({\cal X})$.

Any remarks will be of help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any $T\in L(\mathbb C^n)$, you can write 
$$
T=\frac{T+T^*}2+i\,\frac {T-T^*}{2i}
$$
so $T$ is a linear combination of selfadjoints. And for each selfadjoint you have the Spectral Theorem saying that they are a linear combination of rank-one projections (which are positive semidefinite of trace one).

The result is even true when $\mathcal X$ is an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, although it is not trivial in that case.

Comment: Wow.. thanks! I was just thinking in the domain of Real field, wasn't aware that properties of matrices can be different depending upon the field. 
Do you know if there are other such matrix-related properties that vary for complex and euclidean (or any other field) space?

Comment: Well, if you use the real field you are exposing yourself to pathologies that are due to the field and not the structure of the operator. For instance not having eigenvalues.